# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java, printf

When running this program, there's a bit of a speedbump that causes it to stop and I get a

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Error. I know it's an error due to the way I'm using the `System.out.printf();` function, but I honestly don't know what to put in place of what I already have. Here's the section of code where the error occurs:

```
System.out.print("   \nYear    Total Savings\n");
System.out.printf("%4s\t%,13.2f\n", "----", "-------------\n");
System.out.printf("%4d\t%,13.2f\n", count, totalSavings);`
```

Comment: Also, I apologize for the formatting. I was messing around with it trying to get indenting right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go ahead and guess it's line 2 there:

```
"%4s\t%,13.2f\n"
```

expects a string and a float value. You've passed in two strings ('----', and '------------'). Not sure what the intent was, so I can't fix the code, beyond suggesting using `%s` but that should be enough to get you where you need to go.

Welcome to SO!